# Pass form data as a parameter of a onclick function using JS DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using DOM to generate a form like this

```js
    const my_form = document.createElement("form");
    my_form.enctype = "multipart/form-data";
    my_form.onsubmit = function(){return false;};

    // inputs here

    const div_submit = document.createElement("div");
    div_submit.className = "form-group";
    const submit = document.createElement("input");
    submit.type = "submit";
    submit.value = "Register";
    submit.onclick = function(){my_function(this.form);};
    div_submit.appendChild(submit);
    my_form.appendChild(div_submit);
```

but my problem is when I set the `onClick` attribute of the submit input. Using `this.form` works when I'm writing directly on html, but when I use JS DOM it says that `this.form` is not defined. How can I get the data from the other inputs and pass it as a parameter of the onCLick function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the `form` element by `my_form`.

and you can get the `form` inputs by

```
my_form.elements
```

which will get all form `inputs`.

You can loop through and get it's values.

```
[my_form.elements].forEach(input => console.log(input.value))
```

For more resources.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements